# Generate timestamp columns based on tracked state changes

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions

I have a table in Hive, as below:

| id | state | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2022-01-01 23:01 |
| A | 0 | 2022-02-13 09:00 |
| A | 1 | 2022-04-04 11:21 |
| A | 0 | 2022-04-15 09:32 |
| A | 0 | 2022-04-27 10:05 |
| B | 1 | 2022-02-03 04:51 |
| B | 0 | 2022-02-14 05:01 |

I need to output two new columns, 'actioned' and 'completed'. Column actioned would be where state = 1 whilst completed would be where state = 0. So from the above table, I'd want to create this output:

| id | actioned | completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-01 23:01 | 2022-02-13 09:00 |
| A | 2022-04-04 11:21 | 2022-04-15 09:32 |
| B | 2022-02-03 04:51 | 2022-02-14 05:01 |

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to identify transitions from state `1` (actioned) to `0` (completed) on the same `id`. Here is an approach using `lead()`:

```
select id, timestamp actioned, lead_timestamp completed
from (
    select t.*,
        lead(state)     over(partition by id order by timestamp) lead_state,
        lead(timestamp) over(partition by id order by timestamp) lead_timestamp
    from mytable t
) t
where state = 1 and lead_state = 0
```